# Why it won't detect that the request is come from edit page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the edit page, if I leave captcha empty, and press "save button", it takes me to #new page and says 'Wrong Captcha!'.
In fact, it should take me to edit page again.
Why my controller won't detect that the request was come from edit page?

**comunity_topics_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :simple_captcha_check, :only => [:update, :create] 


def simple_captcha_check
    if !simple_captcha_valid?
        flash[:error] = 'Wrong Captcha!'

        if request.put? # We came from an edit request
          @community_topic = CommunityTopic.find(params[:id])
          @community_topic.attributes = params[:community_topic]
          render :action => :edit
        elsif request.post? # We came from a new request
          @community_topic = CommunityTopic.new params[:community_topic]
          render :action => :new
        end

    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_index_url, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
  <%= show_simple_captcha(:label => "human authentication") %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topic_index_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

New Update:

**rake routes | grep community_topic**

```
           community_topic_index GET    /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#index
                                 POST   /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#create
             new_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
            edit_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id/edit(.:format) community_topics#edit
                 community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#show
                                 PUT    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#update
                                 DELETE /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the request method is post and not put. To use a put request you should write:

```
<%= form_for @community_topic, url: community_topics_url,
```

Comment: Thanks! If I do that, it shows Routing Error
No route matches [PUT] after I pressed 'update button'

Comment: Can you paste your routes.rb file?

Comment: I've just updated. I think ':as' is messing up my paths, but I'd like to use it so bad.

Comment: i think that the url maps to the update action should be community_topics_url

Comment: `community_topic_index_url` links to list page, and you need the same route helper as for the show path. I suppose in your case it would be `community_topic_url`. Look at rake routes

Comment: @Phobos98 so what should I put instead of **<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_index_url, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>** in order to make it suitable for both new and edit?

Comment: @sailor I added my rake routes. What should I put in order to make it flexible for both new and edit page?

Comment: @MKK i edited my answer. community_topics_url should be mapped to your create/update action (depending if it's a new record or not).

Comment: @sailor Thanks it looks almost there. now it says **No route matches {:controller=>"community_topics", :community_id=>nil}** after pressing **update button**.  It takes me to the url /shop/12/topic/12 instead of /shop/walmart/topic/12

Comment: Sorry, It's my previous comment was wrong. I recommend to remove nesting in your routes (with shallow routes) and pass the topic_id in an hidden field.

Comment: never mind I had a problem with my show action! thanks so much

Comment: @sailor now it returns **Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"community_topics"}** if I go to /shop/walmart/topic/new  you think there is no possible way ?

Answer (score 1):

@MKK `<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_url(@community_topic), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>` but check it within your rake routes

Comment: Thanks!! now it returns **Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"community_topics", :community_id=>#<CommunityTopic id: nil, community_id: 4, user_id: 2, title: nil, body: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, community_topic_icon_file_name: nil, community_topic_icon_content_type: nil, community_topic_icon_file_size: nil, community_topic_icon_updated_at: nil, deleted_at: nil>}**

Comment: Is using nested resource routing with customized **:path and :as** so hard thing just like this??